# why can't i find process class in my System.Diagnostics silverlight project VS 2010

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, process, system.diagnostics

i wanna use process.getprocesses() but it doesn't seem to be in my diagnostics class, why?!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume by your use of the Silverlight Tag you are building a Silverlight application.  Silverlight is a sandboxed instance of the .NET CLR.  As such the concept of a Process is alien to it.  A Silverlight application runs in this sandbox isolated from the rest of the world and should not have access to wider concepts like Processes.

You will find that there are many things you might be familiar with from the full .NET framework which are not present in the Silverlight version for various reasons.